# Hide/Show table in UpdatePanel in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I am developing a web application based on ASP.NET.

I have one UpdatePanel and inside that UpdatePanel, there is a Table and in that table I have one DropDownList and One one more table. So my requirement is to hide/show table based on a selection of item in DropDownList.

Lets say If I select index 1 in DropDown, I want to show table. If I select index 2 I want to hide that table.

If I am not using UpdatePanel, the desired functionality is working fine in other pages, But with UpdatePanel, I am not able to Achieve the same, So Please help me out for the same.

This is my DropDownList

```
<asp:TableCell>
  <asp:DropDownList Width="205px" CssClass="merchant_area_name1" ID="DropDownListConnectionType"
  runat="server" onchange="HideBlockHTTPSParameters()">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:TableCell>
```

This is the javascript function I'm using

```
function HideBlockHTTPSParameters() {
    if (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownListConnectionType').options[document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownListConnectionType').selectedIndex].value == "2") {
        document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_TableHTTPSDetails').style.display = "table";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_TableHTTPSDetails').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

this is my table, which I want to

```
<asp:Table ID="TableHTTPSDetails" runat="server" Width="100%">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="4" Style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;color: #0866C6;">
            HTTPS Connection Details
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="4">
            <hr />
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label CssClass="search_area_textfeild1" ID="LabelInitializationURLBankPanel" runat="server" Text="Initialization URL "></asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox Width="200px" CssClass="merchant_area_name1" ID="TextBoxInitializationURLBankPanel" runat="server" MaxLength="49"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ValidationExpression="http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?" ControlToValidate="TextBoxInitializationURLBankPanel" ErrorMessage="Input valid Initialization URL!"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label CssClass="search_area_textfeild1" ID="LabelTransactionURLBankPanel" runat="server" Text="Transaction URL"></asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox Width="200px" CssClass="merchant_area_name1" ID="TextBoxTransactionURLBankPanel" runat="server" MaxLength="49"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ValidationExpression="http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?" ControlToValidate="TextBoxTransactionURLBankPanel" ErrorMessage="Input valid Transaction URL!"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label CssClass="search_area_textfeild1" ID="LabelRouteIndicatorBankPanel" runat="server" Text="Route Indicator"></asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox Width="200px" CssClass="merchant_area_name1" ID="TextBoxRouteIndicatorBankPanel" runat="server" MaxLength="9"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label CssClass="search_area_textfeild1" ID="LabelCountryCodeBankPanel" runat="server" Text="Country Code"></asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox Width="200px" CssClass="merchant_area_name1" ID="TextBoxCountryCodeBankPanel" runat="server" MaxLength="9"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

So can I use javascript with UpdatePanel? Or I am making some mistake?

Comment: once you have the page open in a browser, view its source and check the full name of the control you are trying to hide. I think you are missing something from the name. Like ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_TableHTTPSDetails_DropDownListConnectionType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Assign events programatically for server side controls.  See [HERE](http://forums.asp.net/t/1104755.aspx)

```
yourDropDownList.Attributes["onChange"] = "someJavaScriptFunction();";
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, But its not working in my case.

document.getelementbyid for my DropDownList is giving null value.

Comment: If you are trying to reference the server control in Javascript, you will need to use <% yourDropDownList.ClientID %> instead of the id you've assigned to the control.